# Compiler: "implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, juce

I've searched far and wide for a solution, and while many people have run into this problem, I just can't seem to make the connection between the responses, and what I'm doing wrong.

I've taken the liberty of distilling my program into the simplest form that will still produce this error (as far as I can tell):

```
#ifndef MAINCOMPONENT_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINCOMPONENT_H_INCLUDED

#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"

class MyClass : public Timer {
public:
    MyClass () {}
    ~MyClass (void) {}
    void timerCallback () override {}
};

class MainContentComponent  : public Component {
public:
    MainContentComponent () {
        //============ Removing the following line
        //============ makes the error go away
        myClasses.erase(myClasses.begin());
    }

    ~MainContentComponent () {}

private:
    std::vector<MyClass> myClasses;

};

Component* createMainContentComponent() { return new MainContentComponent(); }

#endif  // MAINCOMPONENT_H_INCLUDED
```

Like I've pointed out, removing

```
myClasses.erase(myClasses.begin());
```

will make the error disappear. What will also make the error disappear, is if I remove the Timer inheritance from MyClass (as well as its pure virtual function).

Here's the whole [error message (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzRaD.jpg). Besides the human-readable parts, it seems utterly undecipherable to me.

Can anybody tell me what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: `Timer` is not copy assignable, so neither is `MyClass`. `vector::erase` need to move elements around by assigning the elements. Ergo error.

Comment: The contained class must be at least [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) if you want to use [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), and `Timer` obviously isn't. Provide your own copy assign or move assign operator for `MyClass`.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks for the quick responses guys. Would making an assignable Timer be a trivial matter? E.g. creating a class that inherits both Timer, and is_move_assignable. Also, is there some reason that Timer is not already move assignable?

Comment: @MaxwellCE It's not a matter of inheriting is_move_assignable, it's a matter of making sure your class does the right thing when someone move-assigns it.

Comment: `Would making an assignable Timer be a trivial matter` without knowing the details of the base class, it's impossible to say. `is there some reason that Timer is not already move assignable` according to your error message the copy assign operator has been explicitly deleted by design, as to why this is the case you'll need to read the lib documentation.

Comment: If your problem is that you don't know how to make a list of `MyClass`es: have you considered using a `vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>`?

Comment: You could also have `MyClass` *contain* an `std::unique_ptr<Timer>` (unless it's absolutely required by your design that `MyClass` inherit publicly from `Timer`).